# How to print new added records in real time?

Tags: mysql

I have a python script continuously adding records to a MySQL database. Is there a way to print the new added records only in real time in MySQL commandline?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a way, using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, mysql supports [triggers for insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html). Perhaps something like:

```
create trigger ins_transaction AFTER INSERT ON tbl select new into outfile filename.txt;
```

And then put a script that reads from filename.txt to your webpage, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi

print('Content-Type: text/plain')
print()

with open('filename.txt') as fin:
    print(fin.read())
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wouldn't that be horrible I/O performance? Why not just have the python script output to the text file alongside adding to the database?

Comment: Because that wouldn't, strictly speaking, be *real time*, which is what was requested by OP

Comment: `new added records only in real time in MySQL commandline?` was his request, which strictly, isn't what you accomplished either. Also, what I suggested in the previous comment is real time. I don't see how it isn't real time.

Comment: See the edit I've made to my answer and tell me how it doesn't solve OPs problem?

Comment: thanks for sharing the light. It's not a production environment so performance is not a big deal in the current stage. I just want to know if the real-time displaying of new records in mysql command line is doable. I don't need to update the web page in real time, the python script does display the new information it got, and I would like to confirm a that in DB at the same time. I will have a try with the trigger. thanks!

Comment: After you've done so, would be kind enough to accept this answer?